# Putting unsanitized data in header() function

Tags: php, security, header, sanitization

Am I leaving my site vulnerable to attack by not filtering data inside a header redirect?

For example:

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];

header("Location: /bar.php?foo=$foo");

die();
```

if the answer is yes, what types of attacks are they, and is simply escaping the data with htmlentities a viable solution?

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];

$foo = htmlentities($foo);

header("Location: /bar.php?foo=$foo");

die();
```

Comment: `htmlentities` doesn't "clean" anything; it merely encodes characters which have a special meaning *in HTML.* Since there's no HTML involved here this is very pointless. In fact, you'll likely make it worse, since HTML entities are encoded with `&..`, and `&` has its own special meaning in URLs. Please read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: plus i can think of few reasons to redirect based on what you have provided. Listen you will only have a certain number of pages to redirect to, do something like `switch()` and make sure you totally control the redirect.

Comment: @deceze thanks for the advice. I'll read through that now.

Comment: You should use `urlencode()` to encode values that are put into URL parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL parameters are not executed, so you're not opening yourself up to attack. However, failing to encode the data may cause the parameter to be interpreted incorrectly. You should use `urlencode()`:

```
$foo = urlencode($foo);
header("Location: /bar.php?foo=$foo");
```